# Adding Row values as Columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the following table in pandas (notice how the item repeats for each warehouse)

| id | Item | Warehouse | Price | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cake | US: California | 30 | 20 |
| 1 | Cake | US: Chicago | 30 | 20 |
| 2 | Meat | US: California | 40 | 10 |
| 2 | Meat | US: Chicago | 40 | 10 |

And I need to add each warehouse as a separate column like this:

| id | Item | Warehouse 1 | Warehouse 2 | Price | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cake | US: California | US: Chicago | 30 | 20 |
| 2 | Meat | US: California | US: Chicago | 40 | 10 |

Data:

```
{'id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
 'Item': ['Cake', 'Cake', 'Meat', 'Meat'],
 'Warehouse': ['US: California',
  'US: Chicago',
  'US: California',
  'US: Chicago'],
 'Price': [30, 30, 40, 40],
 'Cost': [20, 20, 10, 10]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `assign` a number to each warehouse for each id using `groupby` + `cumcount`; then `pivot`:

```
out = (df.assign(col_idx=df.groupby('Item').cumcount().add(1))
       .pivot(['id', 'Item', 'Price', 'Cost'], 'col_idx', 'Warehouse')
       .add_prefix('Warehouse ').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=[None]))
```

or you could use `groupby` + `agg(list)`; then construct a DataFrame with the Warehouse column and `join`:

```
out = df.groupby(['id', 'Item', 'Price', 'Cost']).agg(list).reset_index()
out = (out.drop(columns='Warehouse')
       .join(pd.DataFrame(out['Warehouse'].tolist(), columns=['Warehouse 1', 'Warehouse 2'])))
```

Output:

```
   id  Item  Price  Cost     Warehouse 1  Warehouse 2
0   1  Cake     30    20  US: California  US: Chicago
1   2  Meat     40    10  US: California  US: Chicago
```